# PythonでのQRコードに伴うエラーに関しまして

Tags: python

PythonでQRコードを作成しようとしたところ下記のようにエラーが出ました。
対応についてご教示いただけますと幸いです。

https://web-lh.fromation.co.jp/archives/10000053001

参考にしたサイトに「今回は”qrcode”を使用しますので、予めインストールしておいてください。」とあるので原因の一つはそれをインストールしていないということなのだと思うのですが、インストールの流れというのはどのようなものなんでしょうか？

```
pip install qrcode
Requirement already satisfied: qrcode in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (7.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from qrcode) (0.4.5)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

```
img.save('img.save(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\ミーティング.png')
img = qrcode.make('https://www.google.com/?hl=ja')
img.save('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ミーティング.png')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18508\665761397.py in <module>
----> 1 img = qrcode.make('https://www.google.com/?hl=ja')
      2 img.save('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ミーティング.png')

NameError: name 'qrcode' is not defined
```

Comment: 参照記事に書いてあるような`import qrcode`の行を記述してあるのか？ 記述していても実行しているのかどうか？ そのあたりの情報が書かれていないので判断できないでしょう。(つまり`import qrcode`を実行していないのでは？ ということです)

Comment: 実行というのはどうすればよいんです？

Comment: 既に`img = qrcode.make(...`の箇所で実行しているのでは？ それと同じことを`import qrcode`と入力した箇所で行えば良いでしょう。使い方の概要はこんな記事を探して参考にしてみてください。[【初心者向け】Jupyter Notebookの使い方！インストール方法から解説](https://udemy.benesse.co.jp/development/python-work/jupyter-notebook.html), [図解！Jupyter Labを徹底解説！(インストール・使い方・拡張機能)](https://ai-inter1.com/jupyter-lab/)